# Mysql selet multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

As seen in the code below i have to select multiple values to be exported to my database. `'_shipping_first_name'` AND `'_shipping_last_name'`

How is it possible to make the MySQL work with two values connected?

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `wpd2_postmeta`
WHERE meta_key='_shipping_first_name'(value 2 here) 
AND post_id='12017'
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

SELECT meta_value FROM `wpd2_postmeta` where meta_key=**concat('_shipping_first_name', value2)** and post_id='12017'

Comment: what is you table structure and expected output?